# How to separate issues by a vertical margin

Tags: formatting, text

I have put any statements to the list of questions: My code: [image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[lmargin=3cm,tmargin=3cm,rmargin=2cm,bmargin=2cm]{geometry} \usepackage{amssymb} \usepackage{fancyhdr}  \pagestyle{fancy}

\headheight=14pt \lhead{\lfloor PLEIAD \rfloor  \text{Olimpíadas de Ciências Naturais}} 

\rhead{ Lista 2. Problemas}   % <================================================== \cfoot{} % <============================================== no pagenumber

\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}  \usepackage[brazil]{babel}  \usepackage{enumerate}  \newcommand{\quest}[1]{ \vspace{.8cm} \noindent\textbf{Questão #1. } }

\usepackage{amsmath}  \usepackage{graphicx}

%\usepackage{blindtext} % <======================= to generate dummy text

\everymath{\displaystyle}


\begin{document}   % \Blindtext % <================================= create dummy text here %

\newcommand{\opt}[2]{\begin{enumerate}[a) ]  \item #1 \item #2 \end{enumerate}}




\rfoot{\textit{ \resizebox{!}{0.25cm}{Date}}}

\bigskip

\noindent\textbf{Quest 1.} Dori and Ariel are playing with Mr. Fin's coin collection. When taking two special coins they noticed that one of them has a radius five times larger than the other. They decide to leave the larger coin still and see how many turns the other coin takes to circle the standing coin. How many turns does the small coin make?

\bigskip

(A\noindent$  )\ 12$  \hfill$  \ (B )\ 10$  \hfill$ (C )\ 11$  \hfill$ (D  )\ 121$  \hfill$  (E )\ 3$

\quest{2}  Dori and Ariel are playing with Mr. Fin's coin collection. When taking two special coins they noticed that one of them has a radius five times larger than the other. They decide to leave the larger coin still and see how many turns the other coin takes to circle the standing coin. How many turns does the small coin make?


\bigskip


(A\noindent$  )\ 200$  \hfill$  \ (B )\ 18$  \hfill$ (C )\ 190$  \hfill$  (D  )\ 170$  \hfill$  (E )\ 191$   \quest{3} Dori and Ariel are playing with Mr. Fin's coin collection. When taking two special coins they noticed that one of them has a radius five times larger than the other. They decide to leave the larger coin still and see how many turns the other coin takes to circle the standing coin. How many turns does the small coin make?

\bigskip

(A\noindent$  )\ \frac{11}{6}$  \hfill$  \ (B )\ \frac{16}{11}$  \hfill$ (C )\ 11$  \hfill$  (D  )\ \frac{6}{11}$  \hfill$  (E )\ \frac{3}{11}$   \quest{4} Dori and Ariel are playing with Mr. Fin's coin collection. When taking two special coins they noticed that one of them has a radius five times larger than the other. They decide to leave the larger coin still and see how many turns the other coin takes to circle the standing coin. How many turns does the small coin make?    \bigskip  

(A\noindent$  )\ 12$  \hfill$  \ (B )\ 420$  \hfill$ (C )\ 432$  \hfill$  (D  )\ 2148$  \hfill$  (E )\ 200$   \quest{5} Dori and Ariel are playing with Mr. Fin's coin collection. When taking two special coins they noticed that one of them has a radius five times larger than the other. They decide to leave the larger coin still and see how many turns the other coin takes to circle the standing coin. How many turns does the small coin make?

\bigskip

(A\noindent$  )\ 13$  \hfill$  \ (B )\ 14$  \hfill$ (C )\ 15$  \hfill$ (D  )\ 16$  \hfill$  (E )\ 19$   \quest{6} Dori and Ariel are playing with Mr. Fin's coin collection. When taking two special coins they noticed that one of them has a radius five times larger than the other. They decide to leave the larger coin still and see how many turns the other coin takes to circle the standing coin. How many turns does the small coin make?  \bigskip

(A\noindent$  )\ \frac{1}{4}$  \hfill$  \ (B )\ \frac{1}{5}$  \hfill$ (C )\ \frac{3}{20}$  \hfill$  (D  )\ \frac{1}{2}$  \hfill$  (E )\ \frac{1}{3}$
 

  \quest{7}Dori and Ariel are playing with Mr. Fin's coin collection. When taking two special coins they noticed that one of them has a radius five times larger than the other. They decide to leave the larger coin still and see how many turns the other coin takes to circle the standing coin. How many turns does the small coin make?

\

\bigskip

(A\noindent$  )\ 30$  \hfill$  \ (B )\ 60$  \hfill$ (C )\ 40$  \hfill$ (D  )\ 20$  \hfill$  (E )\ 45$   \quest{8}Dori and Ariel are playing with Mr. Fin's coin collection. When taking two special coins they noticed that one of them has a radius five times larger than the other. They decide to leave the larger coin still and see how many turns the other coin takes to circle the standing coin. How many turns does the small coin make?

\quest{9}Dori and Ariel are playing with Mr. Fin's coin collection. When taking two special coins they noticed that one of them has a radius five times larger than the other. They decide to leave the larger coin still and see how many turns the other coin takes to circle the standing coin. How many turns does the small coin make? \bigskip

(A\noindent$  )\ 60^{\circ}$  \hfill$  \ (B )\ 30^{\circ}$  \hfill$ (C )\ 45^{\circ}$  \hfill$  (D  )\ 35^{\circ}$  \hfill$  (E )\ 120^{\circ}$

\quest{10}Dori and Ariel are playing with Mr. Fin's coin collection. When taking two special coins they noticed that one of them has a radius five times larger than the other. They decide to leave the larger coin still and see how many turns the other coin takes to circle the standing coin. How many turns does the small coin make?

\bigskip

(A\noindent$  )\ n^2$  \hfill$  \ (B )\ n$  \hfill$ (C )\ \frac{n}{2}$ \hfill$  (D  )\ n^3$  \hfill$  (E )\ n^4$

\quest{11}Dori and Ariel are playing with Mr. Fin's coin collection. When taking two special coins they noticed that one of them has a radius five times larger than the other. They decide to leave the larger coin still and see how many turns the other coin takes to circle the standing coin. How many turns does the small coin make?


\quest{12}Dori and Ariel are playing with Mr. Fin's coin collection. When taking two special coins they noticed that one of them has a radius five times larger than the other. They decide to leave the larger coin still and see how many turns the other coin takes to circle the standing coin. How many turns does the small coin make?

\bigskip

(A\noindent$  )\ 256$  \hfill$  \ (B )\ 2048$  \hfill$ (C )\ 2040$  \hfill$  (D  )\ 2016$  \hfill$  (E )\ 3010$   \quest{13}Dori and Ariel are playing with Mr. Fin's coin collection. When taking two special coins they noticed that one of them has a radius five times larger than the other. They decide to leave the larger coin still and see how many turns the other coin takes to circle the standing coin. How many turns does the small coin make?  

\quest{14}Dori and Ariel are playing with Mr. Fin's coin collection. When taking two special coins they noticed that one of them has a radius five times larger than the other. They decide to leave the larger coin still and see how many turns the other coin takes to circle the standing coin. How many turns does the small coin make?


\quest{15}Dori and Ariel are playing with Mr. Fin's coin collection. When taking two special coins they noticed that one of them has a radius five times larger than the other. They decide to leave the larger coin still and see how many turns the other coin takes to circle the standing coin. How many turns does the small coin make?


\bigskip

(A\noindent$  )\ 3$  \hfill$  \ (B )\ 45$  \hfill$ (C )\ 5$  \hfill$  (D  )\ 1$  \hfill$  (E )\ 7$

  \quest{16} Dori and Ariel are playing with Mr. Fin's coin collection. When taking two special coins they noticed that one of them has a radius five times larger than the other. They decide to leave the larger coin still and see how many turns the other coin takes to circle the standing coin. How many turns does the small coin make?

\bigskip

(A\noindent$  )\ 140$  \hfill$  \ (B )\ 20$  \hfill$ (C )\ 1120$  \hfill$  (D  )\ 1212751$  \hfill$  (E )\ 80$   \quest{17}Dori and Ariel are playing with Mr. Fin's coin collection. When taking two special coins they noticed that one of them has a radius five times larger than the other. They decide to leave the larger coin still and see how many turns the other coin takes to circle the standing coin. How many turns does the small coin make?  \bigskip   (A\noindent$  )\ 2010$  \hfill$  \ (B )\ 0$  \hfill$ (C )\ 1$  \hfill$  (D  )\ 2$  \hfill$  (E )\ ab$    \quest{18}Dori and Ariel are playing with Mr. Fin's coin collection. When taking two special coins they noticed that one of them has a radius five times larger than the other. They decide to leave the larger coin still and see how many turns the other coin takes to circle the standing coin. How many turns does the small coin make?

 

 \bigskip


(A\noindent$  )\ 200$  \hfill$  \ (B )\ 210$  \hfill$ (C )\ 400$  \hfill$  (D  )\ 51$  \hfill$  (E )\ \frac{2}{3}$

  \quest{19} Dori and Ariel are playing with Mr. Fin's coin collection. When taking two special coins they noticed that one of them has a radius five times larger than the other. They decide to leave the larger coin still and see how many turns the other coin takes to circle the standing coin. How many turns does the small coin make?

\quest{20} Dori and Ariel are playing with Mr. Fin's coin collection. When taking two special coins they noticed that one of them has a radius five times larger than the other. They decide to leave the larger coin still and see how many turns the other coin takes to circle the standing coin. How many turns does the small coin make?

\quest{21}Dori and Ariel are playing with Mr. Fin's coin collection. When taking two special coins they noticed that one of them has a radius five times larger than the other. They decide to leave the larger coin still and see how many turns the other coin takes to circle the standing coin. How many turns does the small coin make?  \bigskip


(A\noindent$  )\ 100800$  \hfill$  \ (B )\ 5040$  \hfill$ (C )\ 25200$ \hfill$  (D  )\ 20160$  \hfill$  (E )\ 14400$

\quest{22}Dori and Ariel are playing with Mr. Fin's coin collection. When taking two special coins they noticed that one of them has a radius five times larger than the other. They decide to leave the larger coin still and see how many turns the other coin takes to circle the standing coin. How many turns does the small coin make?

\quest{23} Dori and Ariel are playing with Mr. Fin's coin collection. When taking two special coins they noticed that one of them has a radius five times larger than the other. They decide to leave the larger coin still and see how many turns the other coin takes to circle the standing coin. How many turns does the small coin make? \bigskip


(A\noindent$  )\ \frac{43}{54}$  \hfill$  \ (B )\ \frac{11}{36}$  \hfill$ (C )\ 067$  \hfill$  (D  )\ \frac{13}{54}$  \hfill$  (E )\ \frac{13}{16}$ 

\quest{24}Dori and Ariel are playing with Mr. Fin's coin collection. When taking two special coins they noticed that one of them has a radius five times larger than the other. They decide to leave the larger coin still and see how many turns the other coin takes to circle the standing coin. How many turns does the small coin make? \bigskip

(A\noindent$  )\ 7$  \hfill$  \ (B )\ 9$  \hfill$ (C )\ 6$  \hfill$  (D  )\ 10$  \hfill$  (E )\ 5$ 


\quest{25} Dori and Ariel are playing with Mr. Fin's coin collection. When taking two special coins they noticed that one of them has a radius five times larger than the other. They decide to leave the larger coin still and see how many turns the other coin takes to circle the standing coin. How many turns does the small coin make? \bigskip


(A\noindent$  )\ 10085$  \hfill$  \ (B )\ 2017$  \hfill$ (C )\ 6$  \hfill$  (D  )\ 20160$  \hfill$  (E )\ 10091$     \newpage   \begin{center}
    \resizebox{!}{0.5cm}{Answers} \end{center}

\quest{1}\noindent$  \ (A)$  \hfill$   \quest{2} \ (C)$  \hfill$ \quest{3}\ (B)$  \hfill$  \quest{4}\ (D)$  \hfill$  \quest{5}\ (D)$  \hfill$  \quest{6} \ (D)$  \hfill$ \quest{7}\ (A) $   \hfill$  \quest{9}\ (B)$  \hfill$  \quest{10}\ (D)$   \hfill$ \quest{12}\ (B)$  \hfill$  \quest{15}\ (A)$  \hfill$  \quest{16}\ (A)$  \hfill$  \quest{17} \ (A)$  \hfill$ \quest{18}\ (B) $   \hfill$  \quest{21}\ (A)$  \hfill$  \quest{23}\ (C)$   \hfill$  \quest{24}\ (A)$  \hfill$  \quest{25}\ (E)$    \end{document}
```

I would like to know how to split the exercise list into two parts as shown in this template (a vertical margin):

[image]

My code indicates errors when using the back, but I don't know why (I'm not seeing differences in formatting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example have to help You:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{color}

\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\setlength{\columnseprule}{1pt} %Separator ruler width
\def\columnseprulecolor{\color{blue}} %Separator ruler colour

\begin{document}



\begin{multicols}{2}
[\section{Section}
Here's another section with another section heading]

Hello, here is some text without a meaning.  This text should show what 
a printed text will look like at this place.

If you read this text, you will get no information.  Really?  Is there 
no information?  Is there.

This will be in a new column, here is some text without a meaning.  This text should show what 
a printed text will look like at this place.

If you read this text, you will get no information.  Really?  Is there 
no information?  Is there.

\blindtext
\blindtext
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]

***And also for whole document You can use `\documentclass[11pt,twocolumn]{article}`***

Comment: how do I make margin spacing? The invisible edge for the visible edge